# How to get list from database field type string

Tags: sql, python-3.x, list, flask, sqlalchemy

I have this list in one column CHAR/STRING in DB:

```
['2020-09-05 10:15:00', '2020-09-05 10:30:00', '2020-09-05 10:45:00', '2020-09-05 11:00:00', '2020-09-05 11:15:00']
```

I get them to python3:

```
 employee_id = request.args.get('id')
            employee = Employee.query.filter_by(id = employee_id).first()
            list_time_em = employee.free_time
            print(list_time_em) 
            for x in list_time_em:
                print(x). #try to print time in list from DB
```

Result

```
['2020-09-05 10:15:00', '2020-09-05 10:30:00', '2020-09-05 10:45:00', '2020-09-05 11:00:00', '2020-09-05 11:15:00']

['2020-09-0510#...etc
[
'
2
0
2
0
-
0
9
-
0
5
1
0
:
1
5
```

I try many ways to get element in LIST like below:

```
2020-09-05 10:15:00
2020-09-05 10:30:00
```

... etc
but i can't
Anyone help me please!
--------SOLUTION-------
Thanks for @Eddy

```
        if request.args.get('do')=='add_job':
            employee_id = request.args.get('id')
            employee = Employee.query.filter_by(id = employee_id).first()
            list_time_em = employee.free_time
            datesStr = list_time_em
            def getDates(datesStr):
                dates = json.loads(datesStr.replace('\'', '"'))  # make sure we dont break when parsing
                return dates

            dates = getDates(datesStr)
            return render_template('add_job.html',list_time_em=dates)
```

i found another way:

```
        if request.args.get('do')=='add_job':
            employee_id = request.args.get('id')
            employee = Employee.query.filter_by(id = employee_id).first()
            list_time_em = employee.free_time
            x = list_time_em
            ls = x.strip('[]').replace('"','').split(',')
            print(ls)
           
            return render_template('add_job.html',list_time_em=ls)
```

Comment: where is the error, you are just printing each characters one by one.

Comment: i want to get timestamp: '2020-09-05 10:15:00' ... etc,

Comment: Looks like you've stored string representations of Python lists. You should fix the source of the data to use some more suitable (and stable) representation, such as JSON, **or even better**: change the schema to store employee's free time in its own table, one row per entry. In fixing the data you can use `ast.literal_eval()` to convert the string representations of Python lists to proper lists (instead of hacking with `str.replace()` and JSON).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use json library to accomplish this

```
import json

datesStr = "['2020-09-05 10:15:00', '2020-09-05 10:30:00', '2020-09-05 10:45:00', '2020-09-05 11:00:00', '2020-09-05 11:15:00']"

def getDates(datesStr):
    dates = json.loads(datesStr.replace('\'', '"')) # make sure we dont break when parsing
    return dates

dates = getDates(datesStr)

for date in dates:
    print(date)
```

in your specific example:

```
import json

def getDates(datesStr):
    dates = json.loads(datesStr.replace('\'', '"')) # make sure we dont break when parsing
    return dates

employee_id = request.args.get('id')
            employee = Employee.query.filter_by(id = employee_id).first()
            list_time_em = employee.free_time
            dates = getDates(list_time_em)
            for date in dates:
                print(date). #try to print time in list from DB
```

Comment: Hi Eddy, i also want to render getDates to jinja2, how to use it :)

Comment: Hi, sorry, I have (or I didnt have) no idea what jinja2 is, but by quickly searching I found it is a html render engine for phyton, so, you just need to expose the result that getDates() gives into a variable and use that variable into the html template code, something like this should work:

``` 
from jinja2 import Template

dateList = getDates(datesStr)
template = Template('Dates: <ul>{% for date in dates %}<li>{{date}}</li>{% endfor %}</ul>')
template.render(dates=dateList)
```

Answer (score 1):

**This is using mysql library**
import mysql.connector

```
            mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
              host="localhost",
              user="root",
              password="",
              database="closer"
            )
            mycursor = mydb.cursor()

            mycursor.execute("SELECT message FROM message")

            myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
            li=list()
            for x in myresult:
                li.append(x)
            print(li)
```

Comment: result: ['[', "'", '2', '0', '2', '0', '-', '0', '9', '-', '0', '5', ' ', '1', '0', ':', '1', '5', ':', '0', '0', "'", ',', ' ', "'", '2', '0', '2', '0', '-', '0', '9', '-', '0', '5', ' ', '1', '0', ':', '3', '0', ':', '0', '0', "'", ',', ' ', "'", '2', '0', '2', '0', '-', '0', '9', '-', '0', '5', ' ', '1', '0', ':', '4', '5', ':', '0', '0', "'", ',', ' ', "'", '2', '0', '2', '0', '-', '0', '9', '-', '0', '5', ' ', '1', '1', ':', '0', '0', ':', '0', '0', "'", ',', ' ', "'", '2', '0', '2', '0', '-', '0', '9', '-', '0', '5', ' ', '1', '1', ':', '1', '5', ':', '0', '0', "'", ']']

Comment: i try to render time stamp to html, one by one like: 2020-09-05 10:15:00. {% for free_time in list_time_em %}
                                <div class="text-center text-dark">{{ x }}</div>
                                <option value="{{ free_time }}">{{ free_time }}</option>
                            {% endfor %}

Comment: let me inttall a dbms library in python

Comment: thank you, i also update solution :) i use: SQLAlchemy

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for @Eddy

```
        if request.args.get('do')=='add_job':
            employee_id = request.args.get('id')
            employee = Employee.query.filter_by(id = employee_id).first()
            list_time_em = employee.free_time
            datesStr = list_time_em
            def getDates(datesStr):
                dates = json.loads(datesStr.replace('\'', '"'))  # make sure we dont break when parsing
                return dates

            dates = getDates(datesStr)
            return render_template('add_job.html',list_time_em=dates)
```

i found another way:

```
        if request.args.get('do')=='add_job':
            employee_id = request.args.get('id')
            employee = Employee.query.filter_by(id = employee_id).first()
            list_time_em = employee.free_time
            x = list_time_em
            ls = x.strip('[]').replace('"','').split(',')
            print(ls)
           
            return render_template('add_job.html',list_time_em=ls)
```